# How to prevent reverse shared element transition

Tags: android, android-transitions

I have a litle problem.

I have a fragment A with a list and an activity B with also a list.
Now A and B have an image in common, so I set up an shared element transition and it works on the way from A to B.

But I don't want to have the reverse transition if I press the back button.
So I don't call in B `supportFinishAfterTransition` instead of `finish`. But now there is some ugly animation:

*B disappears normally except the image. The image stays in foreground until A is visible in the background and then disappears.*

How can I prevent this? I want the normal behavior like if I would call `finish` or `onBackPressed`.

Greets

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution.

I have played around a bit and if you override `onBackPressed()` 
and call `finish()` instead of `super.onBackPressed()`, It works.

Comment: supportLib 27.1.1, i have to use `finish()` to disable shared elements transition on  return and reenter to A

Comment: Hey, see my answer. Much cleaner to override finishAfterTransition()

Answer (score 6):

just stumbled upon this problem and there's a cleaner solution..

Just override finishAfterTransition(). You should have a boolean in your base class maybe, so it will look like this:

```
final override fun finishAfterTransition() {
    if (myShouldAllowReverseTransitionsBoolean) {
        super.finishAfterTransition()
    } else {
        super.finish()
    }
}
```